# Can you write to the sas log to indicate where a current script is, i.e. the line number for example?

Tags: sas

I want the log to be updated mid script so I know how much of the program has completed.  I know about the 'put' command but this only seems to work in the final printed '.log' file after I have recieved my notifcation as either "Exit 2","Exit 1" or "Done".

Comment: How are you calling SAS?  This is one of those "it depends" questions.

Comment: I calling sas through the Bash command line like this: 'sas -noterminal myscrpt.sas &' @DomPazz

Comment: Write the statements to a file that will be updated mid run. I think you likely only have access to the log once the process completes.

Comment: @Reeza that is incorrect.  The log in batch mode is written to during the run.  On *nix systems you can use `tail -f blah.log` to follow along as the job runs.  There is a buffing mechanism, however, so it is not fully real time.

Comment: @DomPazz thanks. If all you want is processing status, I think a separate file still makes sense. The log has different information. Personal preference I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In batch mode, the log is written to as the process runs.  There is a buffering mechanism that means you cannot follow in perfect real time, but for big jobs it is close.  Assuming (based on your command) you are on a Unix/Linix system:

```
tail -f blah.log
```

Will output the log as it is written to your terminal.

As Reeza mentioned in the comments, your other option is to write to a separate file during the run.

```
filename status "~/status.log";

data _null_;
file status ;
now = datetime();
put "Start at " now datetime.;
run;

<other stuff>

data _null_;
file status mod;
now = datetime();
put "I'm here at at " now datetime.;
run;

...
```

You can then use the same `tail -f ~/status.log` command to follow that file and see where processing has passed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will try it out tomorrow and select as answer if it works :).